# How to use a variable as part of url in robot framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to go to an url using some variables in the path. The code sample is as follows:

```
go to    http://localhost:5000/api/v1/${ind_id_r}
```

When i try to run it, it actually tries to open the url as is , i.e " http://localhost:5000/api/v1/${ind_id_r}" instead of replacing the variable ${ind_id_r} in the url.

Is there any way to make Robot Framework to replace the variable t its value and navigate to the correct url?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you show in your code example should work. I am unable to duplicate the error that you say you get. Please provide a [mcve], with a focus on _complete_

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was to use Catenate function and pass the value as the url.

```
${Req}  Catenate    SEPARATOR=  http://localhost:5000/  ${ind_id_r}
go to   ${Req}
```